# stacked bar chart summing features value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am a new user of Python 2.7 and would like to display a stacked bar chart from a dataframe called data on my Jupiter Notebook.
the dataframe has several columns to describe a user: name, role (parents, grandparents, children), number of comments, number of likes and number of posts.
I would like to display a stacked bar chart with the different roles on the x axis and sum up for each role how many posts, comments and like have been done.

I tried this code but it does not show the results I am expecting

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

data.groupby(['Role', 'Discussion','Posts','Comments',
              'Likes']).sum().unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

Comment: Can you provide us with some data so we can try it ourselves?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the index to be `Role` which should then put it on the x-axis.

```
data.groupby(['Role', 'Discussion','Posts','Comments',
              'Likes']).sum().unstack().set_index('Role').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, you would like to combine online activities by family role eliminating names?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=['Comments', 'Likes', 'Posts','Discussion'])
data['Role'] = np.random.choice(['Child','Parent', 'Grandparent'],size=(100, 1))
data['Name'] = np.random.choice(['Mary','Dorothy','John','Max','Alan','Kevin','Leon'],size=(100, 1))

grpByRole = data.groupby(['Role'])['Posts','Comments','Likes', 'Discussion'].aggregate(np.sum)
ax = grpByRole.plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = True, colormap = 'winter',
 title = 'Activities by Role', rot = 0)
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. it is exactly what I wanted to obtain! :-). great job. wish you a nice WE